# Ain't there nothing up my sleeves

Tags: code-golf, math, kolmogorov-complexity

Note: reference to [Nothing up my sleeve number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nothing_up_my_sleeve_number).

Your task is to take no input and generate this exact output:

```
d76aa478 e8c7b756 242070db c1bdceee f57c0faf 4787c62a a8304613 fd469501
698098d8 8b44f7af ffff5bb1 895cd7be 6b901122 fd987193 a679438e 49b40821
f61e2562 c040b340 265e5a51 e9b6c7aa d62f105d 02441453 d8a1e681 e7d3fbc8
21e1cde6 c33707d6 f4d50d87 455a14ed a9e3e905 fcefa3f8 676f02d9 8d2a4c8a
fffa3942 8771f681 6d9d6122 fde5380c a4beea44 4bdecfa9 f6bb4b60 bebfbc70
289b7ec6 eaa127fa d4ef3085 04881d05 d9d4d039 e6db99e5 1fa27cf8 c4ac5665
f4292244 432aff97 ab9423a7 fc93a039 655b59c3 8f0ccc92 ffeff47d 85845dd1
6fa87e4f fe2ce6e0 a3014314 4e0811a1 f7537e82 bd3af235 2ad7d2bb eb86d391
```

A trailing newline is optional.

The MD5 hash for the version **with** trailing newline is:

- `FC1D37B5295177E7F28509EC9197688F`

The MD5 hash for the version **without** trailing newline is:

- `FAC194EC5EFD2E5A5AC07C2A4925699B`

#### How the string is generated

Those 64 strings are actually the 64 hexadecimal numbers [used in the MD5 hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Pseudocode).

The pseudocode for them:

```python
numbers = floor(2^32 × abs(sin(i))) for i in [1,2,...,64]
```

The reference Python code:

```python
from math import*
for i in range(8):print" ".join("{:08x}".format(int(abs(2**32*sin(-~j))))for j in range(8*i,8*i+8))
```

Ungolfed:

```python
from math import*
for i in range(8):
    temp = []
    for j in range(8*i,8*i+8):
        temp += ["{:08x}".format(int(abs(2**32*sin(j+1))))]
    print " ".join(temp)
```

Comment: So we need to add one newline every 8 numbers?

Comment: @DenkerAffe Yes.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>26</s> <s>24</s> 23 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
64RÆSA‘æ«32Ḟb⁴Ḋ€‘ịØhs8G
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=NjRSw4ZTQeKAmMOmwqszMuG4nmLigbThuIrigqzigJjhu4vDmGhzOEc&input=)

#### How it works

```
64RÆSA‘æ«32Ḟb⁴Ḋ€‘ịØhs8G  Main link. No arguments.

64R                      Yield [1, ..., 64].
   ÆS                    Apply sine to each.
     A                   Take absolute values.
      ‘                  Increment.
                         This avoid padding the hex strings to 8 characters.
       æ«32              Left-shift by 32 units.
           Ḟ             Floor.
            b⁴           Convert to base 16 (list of integers).
              Ḋ€         Remove the first digit of each, undoing the increment.
                ‘        Increment each base 16 digit (for 1-based indexing).
                 ịØh     Index into "0123456789abcdef".
                    s8   Split into chunks of length 8.
                      G  Grid; separate columns by spaces, rows by linefeeds.
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, <s>86</s> <s>77</s> 76 bytes

```python
import math
n=0;exec(",\nn+=1;print'%08x'%(2**32*abs(math.sin(n)))"*8)[1:]*8
```

Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/0umdT6).

#### How it works

Python 2's [`print` statement](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/print.html) has a quirk: It appends a newline to the result of its expression, unless it is followed by a trailing `,`; in this case, it appends a space. While that's usually annoying when golfing (as there's no short way to print without trailing whitespace), it's perfect for this task.

We repeat the string `,\nn+=1;print'%08x'%(2**32*abs(math.sin(n)))` eight times, chop off the leading comma with `[1:]`, and repeat the result eight times. The string that `exec` executes composed of eight identical copies of the following code.

```python
n+=1;print'%08x'%(2**32*abs(math.sin(n))),
n+=1;print'%08x'%(2**32*abs(math.sin(n))),
n+=1;print'%08x'%(2**32*abs(math.sin(n))),
n+=1;print'%08x'%(2**32*abs(math.sin(n))),
n+=1;print'%08x'%(2**32*abs(math.sin(n))),
n+=1;print'%08x'%(2**32*abs(math.sin(n))),
n+=1;print'%08x'%(2**32*abs(math.sin(n))),
n+=1;print'%08x'%(2**32*abs(math.sin(n)))
```

Each line increments the variable **n** (initialized by `n=0`), applies the format string `%08x` (lowercase hexadecimal representation, left-padded with zeroes to length 8, of the integer part of its argument) to **2<sup>32</sup>** times the absolute value of the sine of **n**, and prints the resulting string either with a trailing space or a trailing linefeed.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <s>31</s> 27 bytes

Thanks to @Dennis for saving 4 bytes!

```
jjL;c8mt.Hs*^2 32h.a.tdZS64
```

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jjL%3Bc8mt.Hs*%5E2+32h.a.tdZS64&debug=0)

### Explanation

```
jjL;c8mt.Hs*^2 32h.a.tdZS64

      m                 S64   # map over [1...64]
          s*^2 32h.a.tdZ      # floor(2^32 * abs(sin(d))+1)
       t.H                    # convert to hex-string and discard the first digit
    c8                        # split into 8 parts
jjL;                          # join on whitespaces and then on newlines
```

Comment: You can save a few bytes with `jjL;c8mt.Hs*^2 32h.a.tdZS64`.

Comment: @Dennis Thats clever, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 28 bytes

```
64:Y,|32W*k16YAkZ{Zc72e!3LZ)
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=NjQ6WSx8MzJXKmsxNllBa1p7WmM3MmUhM0xaKQ&input=)

Pretty straightforward computation. Getting the required output format takes almost half the byte count.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>131</s> 81 bytes

```
for(;++$i<65;){echo str_pad(dechex(2**32*abs(sin($i))),8,"0",0).($i%8?" ":"\n");}
```

This is a pretty straight-forward loop with a few conditions for spacing.

@insertusernamehere's shortcuts cut it down by 50 bytes.

Comment: Hello and welcome to PPGC! A few quick tips about your answer : You can get rid of the `<?` tag for posting answers here. As for your code itself, you can get down to 92 bytes by getting rid of the `if`and the multiple `echo` : `for($i=1;$i<65;$i++){echo (($i%8==1)?"\n":" ").str_pad(dechex(2**32*abs(sin($i))),8,"0",0);}`

Comment: You can get it down to *72 bytes*: `for(;++$i<65;)echo str_pad(dechex(2**32*abs(sin($i))),8).($i%8?" ":"⏎");` (replace `⏎ ` with a real newline).

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, <s>69</s> <s>63</s> 58 bytes

```julia
[@printf "%08x%c"√sin(n)^2÷.5^32 n%8>0?32:10for n=1:64]
```

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=W0BwcmludGYgIiUwOHglYyLiiJpzaW4obileMsO3LjVeMzIgbiU4PjA_MzI6MTBmb3Igbj0xOjY0XQ&input=)

#### How it works

For each **n** between **1** and **64**, we compute `√sin(n)^2÷.5^32` and `n%8>0?32:10`, apply string formatting with `"%08x%c"` and print to STDOUT.

- `√sin(n)^2` computes the absolute value of **sin(n)**. `abs(sin(n))` is equally short (in bytes), but it would require a space to separate it from the format string.

  `÷.5^32` divides the previous result by **0.5<sup>32</sup> = 1 / 2<sup>32</sup>**, effectively multiplying it by **2<sup>32</sup>**. However, `÷` performs *integer* divsion, so the result is truncated.
- `n%8>0?32:10` returns **32** (the code point of a space) whenever **n** is not divisible by **8** and **10** (the code point of a linefeed) otherwise.
- `"%08x%c"` turns the first result into lowercase hexadecimal representation, left-padded with zeroes to length 8; and the second result into a character.

Finally, the array comprehension returns an array of **64** instances of `Nothing`, the return value of `@printf`. Outside a REPL, this does not affect output.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES7), 115 bytes

```
_=>`_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
`.repeat(8).replace(/_/g,_=>(0+(Math.abs(Math.sin(++n))*2**32>>>0).toString(16)).slice(-8),n=0)
```

Includes the trailing newline.

Answer (score 1):

## [///](http://esolangs.org/wiki////), <s>568</s> 567 bytes

```
/!/ f//@/fa/d76aa478 e8c7b756 242070db c1bdceee!57c0@f 4787c62a a8304613!d469501
698098d8 8b44f7af!fff5bb1 895cd7be 6b901122!d987193 a679438e 49b40821
f61e2562 c040b340 265e5a51 e9b6c7aa d62f105d 02441453 d8a1e681 e7d3fbc8
21e1cde6 c33707d6!4d50d87 455a14ed a9e3e905!ce@3f8 676f02d9 8d2a4c8a
ff@3942 8771f681 6d9d6122!de5380c a4beea44 4bdec@9!6bb4b60 bebfbc70
289b7ec6 eaa127@ d4ef3085 04881d05 d9d4d039 e6db99e5 1@27cf8 c4ac5665
f4292244 432aff97 ab9423a7!c93a039 655b59c3 8f0ccc92!feff47d 85845dd1
6@87e4f!e2ce6e0 a3014314 4e0811a1!7537e82 bd3af235 2ad7d2bb eb86d391
```

[Try it online!](http://slashes.tryitonline.net#code=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)

Too bad I can only golf <s>6</s> 7 bytes :-(

To convince you that I can't golf it further, I challenge you to [do better in just ///](http://slashes.tryitonline.net), should you accept it. If you do, [you're a magician](http://cjam.aditsu.net#code=q6%2C2%3E%5Cfew%3A%7E%24e%60%7B0%3D1%3E%7D%2C%7B%7E%2C(*%7E%7D%24Sf*N*&input=d76aa478%20e8c7b756%20242070db%20c1bdceeeF57c0faf%204787c62a%20a8304613Fd469501%0A698098d8%208b44f7afFfff5bb1%20895cd7be%206b901122Fd987193%20a679438e%2049b40821%0Af61e2562%20c040b340%20265e5a51%20e9b6c7aa%20d62f105d%2002441453%20d8a1e681%20e7d3fbc8%0A21e1cde6%20c33707d6F4d50d87%20455a14ed%20a9e3e905Fcefa3f8%20676f02d9%208d2a4c8a%0Afffa3942%208771f681%206d9d6122Fde5380c%20a4beea44%204bdecfa9F6bb4b60%20bebfbc70%0A289b7ec6%20eaa127fa%20d4ef3085%2004881d05%20d9d4d039%20e6db99e5%201fa27cf8%20c4ac5665%0Af4292244%20432aff97%20ab9423a7Fc93a039%20655b59c3%208f0ccc92Ffeff47d%2085845dd1%0A6fa87e4fFe2ce6e0%20a3014314%204e0811a1F7537e82%20bd3af235%202ad7d2bb%20eb86d391), since Martin Ender's code says otherwise (checked)!

People that won the challenge and are worth of crediting (format: `name (id), bytes_golfed`):

- daHugLenny (56258), 1

Comment: [Golfed one more byte.](http://pastebin.com/AR2a53ck)

Comment: @daHugLenny It seems my +/-s need to update...

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>56</s> <s>54</s> 52 bytes

```perl
printf'%08x%s'x64,map{0|2**32*abs sin,$_%8?$":$/}1..64
```

Saved <s>2</s> 4 bytes thanks to @XCali

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvJE1d1cCiQrVYvcLMRCc3saDaSEvL2EgrMalYoTgzT0clXtXCXkXJSkW/1lBPz8zk/38A)

Comment: [Save 2 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvJE1d1cCiQrVYvcLMRCc3saDaoMZIS8vYSCsxqVihODNPRyVe1cJeRclKRb/WUE/PzOT/fwA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: Thanks! forgot about that trick :)

Comment: Actually, you can take off two more by eliminating that altogether.  The `%x` format only considers the integer portion.  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvJE1d1cCiQrVYvcLMRCc3saDaSEvL2EgrMalYoTgzT0clXtXCXkXJSkW/1lBPz8zk/38A "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [K4](https://kx.com/download/), 48 bytes

**Solution:**

```
-1@" "/:'8 8#(,/$4_0x0\:)'_abs sin[1+!64]*/32#2;
```

**Example:**

```
q)k)-1@" "/:'8 8#(,/$4_0x0\:)'_abs sin[1+!64]*/32#2;
d76aa478 e8c7b756 242070db c1bdceee f57c0faf 4787c62a a8304613 fd469501
698098d8 8b44f7af ffff5bb1 895cd7be 6b901122 fd987193 a679438e 49b40821
f61e2562 c040b340 265e5a51 e9b6c7aa d62f105d 02441453 d8a1e681 e7d3fbc8
21e1cde6 c33707d6 f4d50d87 455a14ed a9e3e905 fcefa3f8 676f02d9 8d2a4c8a
fffa3942 8771f681 6d9d6122 fde5380c a4beea44 4bdecfa9 f6bb4b60 bebfbc70
289b7ec6 eaa127fa d4ef3085 04881d05 d9d4d039 e6db99e5 1fa27cf8 c4ac5665
f4292244 432aff97 ab9423a7 fc93a039 655b59c3 8f0ccc92 ffeff47d 85845dd1
6fa87e4f fe2ce6e0 a3014314 4e0811a1 f7537e82 bd3af235 2ad7d2bb eb86d391
```

**Explanation:**

First pass, probably a few tricks left to golf further...

```
-1@" "/:'8 8#(,/$4_0x0\:)'_abs sin[1+!64]*/32#2; / the solution
                                           32#2  / take 2, 32 times (2 2 2 2 2...)
                                         */      / product beginning with left argument
                               sin[     ]        / built-in sine function
                                     !64         / range 0..63
                                   1+            / add 1, so 1..64
                           abs                   / built-in abs function
                          _                      / floor
             (          )'                       / do this together for each
                   0x0\:                         / convert to byte representation
                 4_                              / drop first 4 elements
                $                                / convert to string
              ,/                                 / flatten
         8 8#                                    / reshape to 8x8
   " "/:'                                        / join each with a single space
-1@                                            ; / print to stdout and swallow return
```

Answer (score 0):

### Racket 125 bytes

```
(λ()(for((i(range 1 65)))(printf"~x "(inexact->exact(floor(*(expt 2 32)(abs(sin i))))))(when(= 0(modulo i 8))(printf"~n"))))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define f
  (λ ()
    (for ((i (range 1 65)))
      (printf "~x " (inexact->exact(floor (*(expt 2 32) (abs (sin i)) ))))
      (when(= 0 (modulo i 8)) (printf "~n"))
      )))
```

Testing:

```
(f)
```

Output:

```
d76aa478 e8c7b756 242070db c1bdceee f57c0faf 4787c62a a8304613 fd469501 
698098d8 8b44f7af ffff5bb1 895cd7be 6b901122 fd987193 a679438e 49b40821 
f61e2562 c040b340 265e5a51 e9b6c7aa d62f105d 2441453 d8a1e681 e7d3fbc8 
21e1cde6 c33707d6 f4d50d87 455a14ed a9e3e905 fcefa3f8 676f02d9 8d2a4c8a 
fffa3942 8771f681 6d9d6122 fde5380c a4beea44 4bdecfa9 f6bb4b60 bebfbc70 
289b7ec6 eaa127fa d4ef3085 4881d05 d9d4d039 e6db99e5 1fa27cf8 c4ac5665 
f4292244 432aff97 ab9423a7 fc93a039 655b59c3 8f0ccc92 ffeff47d 85845dd1 
6fa87e4f fe2ce6e0 a3014314 4e0811a1 f7537e82 bd3af235 2ad7d2bb eb86d391
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 37 bytes

36 bytes of code, +1 for `-S` flag.

```
0X8-#_._MMLC(2**32*ABSI++,64)TB16<>8
```

Pretty straightforward implementation. Unfortunately, 10 bytes are needed to left-pad some of the values with `0`. [Try it online!](http://pip.tryitonline.net/#code=MFg4LSNfLl9NTUxDKDIqKjMyKkFCU0krKyw2NClUQjE2PD44&input=&args=LVM)

```
                         ,64          Numbers 0 to 63
                       ++             Increment to get 1 to 64
                     SI               Sine
                   AB                 Absolute value
             2**32*                   Multiply by 2^32
            (               )TB16     Convert to hex (implicitly truncating to int)
          LC                          Lowercase--Pip's base conversion uses uppercase :(
                                 <>8  Group into sublists of size 8
        MM                            Map this function to each item of each sublist:
  8-#_                                  1 if item is length 7, 0 if length 8
0X                                      That many zeros
      ._                                Concatenate to beginning of item
                                      Print separated first by newline then by space (-S)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 34 bytes

```
64{Tsab2 32**.*pd-.b68'0lp}GO8cosp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f/fzKQ6pDgxyUjB2EhLS0@rIEVXL8nMQt0gp6DW3d8iOb@44P9/AA)

```
64      # Literal 64
{
 Ts     # Sin
 ab     # Abs
 2 32** # 2**32
 .*     # Times-by
 pd     # Floor
 -.     # Decrement by 1
 b6     # To base 16
 8'0lp  # Left pad to length 8 with 0s
}GO     # Range from [1, 64] and map
8co     # Chunks of 8
sp      # Pretty print array
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>19</s> 17 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
64LÅ½ÄžJ*hl8jð0:8ô»
```

-2 bytes by taking inspiration from [*@Dennis*' Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/82662/52210) regarding the leading 0s, so make sure to upvote him!

Outputs with trailing newline.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9vc2FiaWX//zY0TMOFwr3DhD7FvkoqaGzigqzCpjjDtMK7//8)

**Explanation:**

```python
64L                # Push a list in the range [1,64]
   Å½              # Take the sine of each
     Ä             # Take the absolute value of that
      >            # Increase it by 1 (to avoid having to pad leading 0s later on)
       žJ*         # Multiply it by builtin 4294967296
          h        # Convert it from integer to hexadecimal
                   # (which implicitly truncates the decimals; and uses uppercase [A-F])
           l       # Convert that hexadecimal string to lowercase
            €¦     # Remove the first character from each (undoing the earlier increment)
              8ô   # Split the list into parts of size 8
                »  # Join each inner list by spaces, and then those strings by newlines
                   # (after which it is output implicitly with trailing newline)
```